# Translate custom values in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp

How can I use `__( )` in CakePHP for translate **variable/custom values**? Like, strings, integer or decimal values?

For example:

```
__('You have $16.52 in your wallet')
```

I try use `sprintf`but doesn't work, like that:

```
sprintf(__("Table %s can't have status changed to Busy. Please check the number and try again"), $table_num)
```

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: I know: "Translate custom values in CakePHP 2.3", but the exactly version is 2.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using >= 2.0:

```
__('You have %s in your wallet', '$16.52');
```

as __() already has %s replacement built in now.